# What's the purpose of an override decorator?

Tags: overriding, decorator

My understanding to the use of a decorator is to add a constraint or extend a function.

A `@override` notation seems to be weird, since it doesn't(and shouldn't) to modify the function.

Then what did the `@override` decorator do?

Comment: Which language? Please include the relevant tag

Comment: Depends on the language, but one possibility would be that it adds a compile-time check to see if the method actually overrides the base class' method (i.e. whether the method signature matches a base class method signature).

Comment: @shree.pat18 I didn't specify a language cause I assume that most language has similar meaning(I thought it might be a common feature).

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen So it might not work as a common decorator? It seems more likely to be used to debug.

Comment: 1) What is your definition of a "common" decorator? 2) Why do you consider `@override` to be a decorator? 3) What is `@override` supposed to do? Since you refuse to specify a language, we're just basing ourselves on your definitions, so there's no way to make an authoritative statement either way.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Sorry for asking such an ambiguous problem. 1) I thought I shouldn't say that. I wonder if there exist a precise definition for a decorator. or what this means in the major part of language.  2) The reason I thought ```@override``` as a decorator is because I thought @ annotation in most language means decorator. 3) I know dartlang has a ```@override``` annotation, maybe we could take this as an example. Thank you in advance.